Can I force sklearn to use float32 instead of float64?
I am building a product recommender that will use the description of products to find similar products and recommend them. I am using CountVectorizer over the description to find semantically similar descriptions, rank them and suggest those similar.
The problem comes when calculating the cosine similarity matrix. My initial dataframe has 47,046 rows so Im coming up with RAM issues both on my local pc and in my Colab notebook.
Checking the count matrix that CountVectorizer I see that it outputs it as int64:
<47046x3607 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 699336 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

There is no issue in casting it to int32 with : count_matrix = count_matrix.astype(np.int32) but still when running the cosinesimilarity  from sklearn it outputs float64 instead of float32 (I confirmed this by testing with a smaller dataset that can be processed fine).
Is there any way to force the use of float32? Or a way to actually solve the high RAM usage with matrices altogether?

How many entries in the output matrix are zero? If there are a lot, and you try dense_output=False, does that help? See also: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html


Is there any way to force the use of float32?

You could cast the input sparse matrix to float32. In my testing, this causes the output array to be float32.
Here's a test program I wrote.
import scipy
import sklearn.metrics
import numpy as np

rvs = scipy.stats.randint(low=0, high=10)

A = scipy.sparse.random(47046, 3607, density=0.0005, data_rvs=rvs.rvs, dtype=np.int64)
print("starting dtype", A.dtype)
print("output dtype", sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity(A, A).dtype)
A = A.astype(np.float32)
print("starting dtype", A.dtype)
print("output dtype", sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity(A, A).dtype)

Output:
starting dtype int64
output dtype float64
starting dtype float32
output dtype float32


Hi Nick!
Thanks for the help and suggestion. I tried it and indeed by saving it first as float32 it maintains the dtype unlike with int32 which defaults back to float64. Sadly i tried again under this option and i still ran out memory in Colab.
I found this odd as after toying a but i saw there is a different environment in colab you can use only for some period of time (unless you are subscribed) and I ran it there and got the matrix to work. Interestingly enough i saved the matrix and it is "only" 8GB big. Any clues why this still would go over the 12GB in colab? (just to educate myself)

@JLd It probably takes more than 8GB of memory to multiply this. One needs the original matrix, the original matrix after normalization, and the destination matrix all in memory at once to calculate this. If dense_output=True, the destination matrix would be 17GB by itself.
